# Retrieving data from two tables in firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from two tables in a database. I understand that if I want to read from a child I do this:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
```

So what do I do for two children?

My data looks like this:

[image: Data example]

Comment: You probably mean some sort of join operation, right? Search for `firebase join` on both google and stack overflow.

Comment: Please make it more specific, and uncover what is in the user_id node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume 2 possibilities for your question.

First: you want to retrieve a child of a child

```
appName{
      "users" : {
        "Bob" : {
          "age" : 20
        }
}
```

In this case to access a specific user you should do:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Bob");
```

But if you mean that you have different child like: users and questions

```
appName{
  "users" : {
    "Bob" : {
      "age" : 20
    }
}

  "questions" : {
    "who am I?" 
    }
}
```

Then, you should make a reference to each one of them:

```
usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
questionsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questions");
```

Comment: This does not seem a valid JSON: `"questions" : {
    "who am I?" 
    }`